# Field must be grouped or aggregated: Name?

Tags: query, aggregate, conga, group-by

I'm working on a query for an invoice template. We want for the "main" products to be displayed on the same list and the one time fees products to be displayed on an other list. We have already did this for a quote template and it works but the invoice doesn't have the same fields and for some reason i get this error "Field must be grouped or aggregated: Name". Here the query im working with:

```
SELECT Doctor__r.Name doctorName,c2g__Product__r.Name productName, c2g__LineDescription__c, SUM(c2g__Quantity__c) Doc_Quantity, SUM(c2g__UnitPrice__c) ListPrice, SUM(c2g__NetValue__c) NetTotal FROM c2g__codaInvoiceLineItem__c WHERE c2g__Invoice__c = {'PV0'} AND Usage__c = FALSE GROUP BY c2g__Product__r.Name, c2g__LineDescription__c
```

Can someone tell me what am i doing wrong? I've been trying and looking for an answer for too long! I'm really not a pro with CongaQueries so any feedback would help!! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

This has little to do with Conga per se; it's in the realm of [SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_sosl_intro.htm). Stripping down the query to the relevant pieces, you have:

```sql
SELECT ... Doctor__r.Name doctorName, ...
FROM   c2g__codaInvoiceLineItem__c
WHERE ... 
GROUP BY c2g__Product__r.Name, c2g__LineDescription__c
```

The problem is that you've asked Salesforce to *group* the results of the query by two fields (`c2g__Product__r.Name, c2g__LineDescription__c`), but you haven't told it how you want the values in the `Doctor__r.Name` field to be aggregated for each group. Since each group will be one "row" in your query results, it cannot contain multiple values for that field.

To do this, you must apply an [*aggregate function*](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions.htm) to the field.

However, it's not especially clear to me what outcome you want. The right answer may be to drop the field entirely, to use an aggregate function in some way that is not clear to me, or to restructure your query.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer! Mainly, i need this query to bring back these fields because they are not directly related to the invoice. So i need to have the product, doctor, description quantity ect in a table. This table will have the main license and/or products that the client wants, so the "usage"/one time fee products can't be shown in this table! So i'm trying to figure out how to have all these field and t omake it so the usage dont pop up in this table!

Comment: So for exemple, if a doctor bought 5 of the same licenses and wants his paper printed out and sent to him, the 5 same products need to be grouped in one line, quantity = 5 and the one time fee needs to not be in there! Hope i'm clear!